# Python string comparison not working properly

Tags: python, parsing, mysql-python, string-comparison

This is my script.

```
import MySQLdb import feedparser import string

def checkunique(t):
    #t1 = ''.join(filter(lambda c: c in string.printable, t))
    cur.execute("SELECT title from linkstwo")
    titles = cur.fetchall()
    for k in titles:
        #k1 = ''.join(filter(lambda c: c in string.printable, k))
        print "'%s'" % k
        if t == k:
            return False
    return True

db = MySQLdb.connect ("localhost","root",password,"torrents") print "DB connection successful" cur  = db.cursor()

url = "https://extratorrent.cc/rss.xml?type=popular&cid=4"

feed = feedparser.parse(url)

print "Parsing successful"


for post in feed.entries:
    t = post.title
    m = post.magneturi
    #print "'%s'" % t
    if checkunique(t):
       cur.execute("INSERT INTO linkstwo (title, maglink) VALUES ('%s', '%s')" % \
                    (t, m))
    db.commit()

print "Script ended"
```

It parses an RSS feed and adds any new entries to a database.

My problem is the the function `checkunique` always returns true and I keep getting duplicate entries. I tried some of the solutions to remove any non-printable characters that might have found its way in, still no luck.

Comment: BTW, that is a very inefficient way to check for uniqueness. You select all the titles again and again... Just put a unique constraint in the database table and fetch duplicate errors when they are triggered.

Comment: Shouldn't you use k[0] in comparison? Your variable called titles should be a tuple of tuples.

Comment: This is a testing script for the real script I'm hoping to build. It is essential I compare the titles this way as I will be adding the new titles to a separate table (download database) as well. Data from that table will be used to download the related torrents in a separate script.

Comment: Mateusz Kleinert. You are a lifesaver. Thank you. I was busting my head for almost 3 hours for this.

Answer (score 0):

It dosen't make sense to query all table every time you execute the `checkunique` function.

I would go with some other approach, you could update your sql query in order to check if the title is already exist.

For example:

```
cur.execute("IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT title FROM linkstwo WHERE title = '%s' ))
    INSERT INTO linkstwo (title, maglink) VALUES ('%s', '%s')" \
                    (t, t, m)))
```

Comment: There are many ways to achieve my goal using sql queries, but here the method in which I achieve it matters as I depend on that method to build my script further.

Answer (score 0):

After editing my script to this, it started functioning as expected.

```
for k in titles:
        #k1 = ''.join(filter(lambda c: c in string.printable, k))
        print "'%s'" % k
        if t == k[0]:
            return False
    return True
```